# Adding an Image at a specific place on an existing image

Tags: image-processing, image, pdf-format

I have created the following PDF: Basically an image, with a description underneath and a space to take some personal notes:

```
m = Import[
   "https://images.pexels.com/photos/36455/rose-red-flower-victor-\
hugo.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=flora-floral-flower-36455.jpg&fm=jpg"];

exportIm = 
 Panel[Style[
   Grid[{{im, 
      SpanFromLeft}, {TextCell[
       Row[{"balabalaablabalb balabalbalbalba"}], 
       TextJustification -> 1, Hyphenation -> False], 
      SpanFromLeft}, {}, {"Notes: "}}, 
    Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, True, True, False}, {False}}, 
    BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1], 7, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Background -> White], 
  Background -> White, ImageSize -> {210, 227}*2]

Export["test.pdf", exportIm]
```

[image]

Now I would like to **add a QR code to the bottom right of the PDF** (which will eventually link to the image on the web).

I now that I can create a QR code...

```
BarcodeImage["123456789", "QR"]
```

**... but I don't know how to include it into the PDF.
Do you know how ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a few options here, but your best bet is to just use the grid system you already have with `Item`, to specify the alignment for the barcode manually. Specifically, we'll do `Item[BarcodeImage["1"], Alignment->Right]` to align to the right edge, coupled with a `SpanFromLeft` to actually place other content in the column (otherwise it doesn't work correctly - I'm not actually certain why that is).

```
exportIm = Panel[Style[Grid[{
 {m, SpanFromLeft},
 {TextCell[Row[{"balabalaablabalb balabalbalbalba"}], 
   TextJustification -> 1, Hyphenation -> False], SpanFromLeft},
 {},
 {"Notes: "},
 {SpanFromLeft, 
  Item[BarcodeImage["123456789", "QR"], Alignment -> Right]}
 }, Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, True, True, False}, {False}},
 BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1], 7, 
FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Background -> White], 
Background -> White, ImageSize -> {210, 227}*2]
```

You can modify the third argument to `BarcodeImage` to choose the size of the QR code.

Other options include `Overlay` and `ImageCompose`. These have various issues though - `Overlay` is a little hard to specify location, and `ImageCompose` requires `Rasterize`ing of both inputs before working.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer ! However, the barcode is not placed at the very bottom of the page. When you export it as pdf you can see that the barcode is below the "Notes" text on the left, but not on the bottom of the page. Do you see an option of how to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you seen my previous comment ?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181370/need-help-for-layout

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed this, good idea adding a separate question.