# Need Help for Layout

Tags: image-processing, grid-layouts

I am preparing pdf's with an image, a description and a QR code linking to that image hosted on the web.

However for now the QR code is always positioned just bellow the description.
I would like to have it always at the same position at the bottom right, not matter how long the description is.

```
m = Import[
       "https://images.pexels.com/photos/36455/rose-red-flower-victor-\
    hugo.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=flora-floral-flower-36455.jpg&fm=jpg"];
    exportIm = 
     Panel[Style[
       Grid[{{m, 
          SpanFromLeft}, {TextCell[
           Row[{"balabalaablabalb balabalbalbalba"}], 
           TextJustification -> 1, Hyphenation -> False], 
          SpanFromLeft}, {}, {"Notes: "}, {SpanFromLeft, 
          Item[BarcodeImage["123456789", "QR", 7], Alignment -> Right]}}, 
        Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, True, True, False}, {False}}, 
        BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1], 7, 
       FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Background -> Gray], Background -> Gray,
       ImageSize -> {210, 297}*2]
```

Generates:

[image]

But what I would like is (QR code bottom right):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change  `{SpanFromLeft, Item[BarcodeImage["123456789", "QR", 7], Alignment -> Right]}` to

```
{Item[BarcodeImage["123456789", "QR", 7], Alignment -> Right], SpanFromLeft}
```

and `{"Notes:"}` to

```
{Item["Notes:", Alignment -> { Left, Top}, ItemSize -> {Full, Scaled[.65]}]}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: I see that I never thanked you for that answer. I am sorry ! Well, thank you very much !!

Comment: @james, my pleasure; thank you for the accept.